# Using simple:rest with accounts-ui and iron router

Tags: rest, meteor, authorization, meteor-accounts

I am authenticating users with accounts-ui and route them with iron router. Now I'd like to call the simple:rest API.

How can a user who is authenticated by accounts-ui make simple:rest calls with his user privileges?
What is the best way to set up a separate way to authenticate+simple:rest  that is compatible with account-ui and iron router?